# CSS - Positioning images next to text

Tags: css, positioning

I'm doing a site in which images need to presented next to textual content - a sort of pseudo two-column layout, as the images and text come from a single html source.

I've found quite a simple way to do this by putting the images as their own paragraphs and floating them. Would there still be a more simpler way (in regards to html) to do this without these extra paragraphs and by only attributing extra css to images?

If the floated image is in the same paragraph than the text, then paragraphs with and without images would be different in width.

**EDIT**: Basically, I'm looking for as simple HTML markup as possible to position images like [this](http://www.widerscreen.fi/2006/3/elokuvallinen_kauhukokemus.htm). The CSS can be complex ;)

```
CSS:
p { width: 500px; }
p.image { float: right; width: 900px; }


Current HTML:
<p class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></p>
<p>Some text here.</p>


Is the above possible with this HTML?
<p><img src="image.jpg" /></p>
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for this?

```
p img { float: right; width: 900px; }
```

This would match all img-tags inside p-tags.
But I recommend always using classes or ids to match CSS rules. Just using the tag name can lead to annoying pitfalls, sooner or later.

**Edit**

Mhm, maybe I got you wrong. You would like to apply `float: right; width: 900px;` to the p-elements, not the img-elements ...

AFAIK there is no way to select a parent of a specific element. It always works in direction PARENT -> CHILD, not CHILD -> PARENT.

Comment: Up-voted, as this is certainly the easiest -and probably leanest- way. I'd suggest maybe adding 'clear: left' but that's probably not necessary.

Comment: Hi, 

not exactly. As the site content will be updated with a wysiwyg editor like TinyMCE by persons without any knowledge of html/css, I'm looking for a way to achieve the image positioning with as little extra markup as possible. 

So classes for images would be ok, I'm just wondering if there's a way to do the above without extra paragraphs. 

Another way to put it: I'm looking for the most simple html markup to achieve this kind of image positioning:
http://www.widerscreen.fi/2006/3/elokuvallinen_kauhukokemus.htm

Answer (score 2):

No. With the img inside the p, you can float the image right but the text will not stay in a column. It will wrap underneath the image. Any right margin or padding you apply to the p will also apply to the img.

Since you have two pieces of related information, I would wrap those in a div and then position them within the div.

```
.info {width:900px;}
.info img {float:right;}
.info p {margin-right:400px;}

<div class="info">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to [Emily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066188/css-positioning-images-next-to-text/1066261#1066261)'s answer.

> No. With the img inside the p, you can
>   float the image right but the text
>   will not stay in a column. It will
>   wrap underneath the image. Any right
>   margin or padding you apply to the p
>   will also apply to the img.

While she's right, as far she goes, there is a workaround. Though it's not ideal:

```
p {position: relative; padding-right: 950px; /* width of the image + 50px margin */ }

img {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

This should put the image in the top-right corner of the `p`, while forcing the text into a column between the left boundary of the `p` element and the 950px right-padding. Not ideal, and a little messy, but it allows for the columnar effect without adding extra tags.

...*unless* you want to add a clearfix `br`(`br.clearfix: display: block; clear: both`) at the end of the paragraph (to force the `p` tag to extend past the image for short paragraphs).

Comment: Positioning the image to the right will work as long as the images are =< in width to the gutter you define with padding on the p. You can use faux columns (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) for the background effect.

Comment: Yeah; I never thought to clarify that -I just took the 900px from the example without thought- though I kinda implied it...maybe...kinda...in the css code-comment. >cough< =)

Answer (score 1):

yes, just tested this,
make sure you use the strict doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<style>
p { width: 500px; position:relative;}
p img { position:absolute; margin-left:520px;}
</style>

<p><img src="PastedImage.jpg" />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I concocted this line of code here to help me position some text exactly where I wanted it. I might be a novice way but it got the job done simply and easily and precise. and all HTML.

```
<a href="http://elonmusk.com" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP: 24px; LEFT:50px;">put your txt in here and use the Top and Left values to position the text precisely where you want it</a>
```

you can also use the href field to make your text a hyperlink or if thats now what you want you can jus delete the href field but be mindful to keep the "

```
<a STYLE="position:absolute; TOP: 24px; LEFT:50px;">txt go here - use Top & Left values to position it. ex. of text with no hyperlink</a>
```

Comment: The `style` attribute overrides every other style (except ones with `!important`, and those aren’t good either), which defeats the point of *Cascading* Style Sheets and makes people use `!important`, and that isn’t good for more or less the same reason. It also just looks messy and breaks the nice separation between presentation and content provided by the platform.